# How can display two horizontal buttons, and below a map

Tags: android, android-layout, button

Currently in my code, buttons are displayed one under another and the map is displayed below them. I want that the two buttons to be displayed on the same line and below the map.

My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/btnProgram"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:text="Program" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/btnAfisareStatii"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:text="Afisare Statii" />        

     <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:apiKey="0ws8opHdf-pIbZUa916nju81kSSlPRK4Wbg_0vg"
     />

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either wrap the two buttons in a horizontal LinearLayout, or use a RelativeLayout, as below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnProgram"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Program" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAfisareStatii"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Afisare Statii" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnProgram"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnAfisareStatii" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/webview" />

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="0ws8opHdf-pIbZUa916nju81kSSlPRK4Wbg_0vg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" android:layout_above="@id/btnProgram">
    </com.google.android.maps.MapView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You should also arrange the webView's, or remove them, if you don't need them

Comment: Can you tell me please how to make buttons to fill each half of row?

Comment: Hmm.. for this you really need to wrap the two buttons in a horizontal `Linearlayout`, with `android:weightSum="1"`, and set `android:layout_weight="0.5"` for each button.

Comment: I did that, but now is displayed only the map, the buttons no longer appear

Comment: Sure enough, if you didn't set well the Linearlayout properties inside the Relative one; I suggest you to  try first to understand how the Linear and Relative layouts are working; read more here:http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html and http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html

Comment: Thanks, I will look over the links

Answer (score 0):

Try with this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  <LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/btnProgram"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:text="Program" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/btnAfisareStatii"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:text="Afisare Statii" />        

</LinearLayout>
 <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0ws8opHdf-pIbZUa916nju81kSSlPRK4Wbg_0vg"
 />

<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webview2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Comment: I did as you said to me, but now the buttons are displayed on the same line and the map does not appear

Answer (score 0):

Set the layout where the buttons are at android:orientation:"horizontal"
Use this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">


 <Button
     android:id="@+id/btnProgram"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="Program" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/btnAfisareStatii"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="Afisare Statii" />
```

`</LinearLayout>`